# additional text display when form field is clicked - react

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, forms

i'm making a form in react and currently when the field is clicked it adds a blue border (which i would like to keep) but i would like some additional text to appear underneath, and i'm not sure how to do this?

basically, i have a field for first name and when its clicked i'd like "Enter your first name" to appear underneath this field.

here's what i currently have:

```
<div className="form-group form-row">
    <label
       id="firstNameLabel"
       className="col-md-2 col-form-label text-md-right"
       htmlFor="firstName1"
       readOnly
    >
      First Name*
    </label>
    <div className="col-md-10">
         <input
         type="text"
         className="form-control"
         name="firstName1"
         ref="firstName1"
         placeholder="First Name"
         value={this.state.firstName1} 
         onChange={this.handleChange} 
         required
     />
     <div className="error" id="firstnameError" />
   </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It goes like this:

In the event you want to watch for, store some flag in state, e.g.

```
this.setState({userClicked:true})
```

The event you want to watch for could be `onFocus`, i.e.

```
<input
     type="text"
     className="form-control"
     name="firstName1"
     ref="firstName1"
     placeholder="First Name"
     value={this.state.firstName1} 
     onFocus={()=>{ this.setState({userClicked:true}) }}
     onChange={this.handleChange} 
     required
   />
```

You can also use `onBlur` to set the flag to false, when input loses focus,
Then in render put below code where you want the notification to appear:

```
....
{this.state.userClicked && <div>Enter first name</div>}
```

Above line will make sure the div is rendered when `userClicked` is true.

Comment: Hi giorgi - I don't know react (I use Vue) but couldn't you do this with just CSS - keep react out of it? Have the div with the text always present (which is good for accessibility) but hidden (`visibility:hidden`) then use the `:focus` selector on the control to change it to `visible`. If you _are_ doing it with react, wouldn't _onFocus_ be enough? (I'm thinking you don't have to watch for click because focus is gained when clicked, and you're already handling focus)

Comment: @StephenP I reworded the answer. It seems you suggest some pure CSS way, I don't know how you'd do that I am not pro in CSS. I think it would be fine. One thing React discourages is to modify DOM directly. Because React should do it. If your CSS approach doesn't violate that, should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `onFocus` and `onBlur` events to achieve that, here is an example:

```
<input
  onFocus={() => this.setState({inputFocused: true})}
  onBlur={() => this.setState({inputFocused: false})}
\>
{this.state.inputFocused && <div>Some message</div>}
```